# Why is my program throwing java.util.InputMismatchException?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am getting an error in my code:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909) 
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
>       at Hello.main(Hello.java:22)

The full code for my example is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int  n = sc.nextInt();
        String[] friends = new String[n];
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            friends[i] = sc.next();
            map.put(friends[i], i);
        }
        int[] money = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int idx = map.get(sc.next());
            int gift = sc.nextInt();
            int M = sc.nextInt();
            int reminder =gift % M;
            int dev = gift / M;
            money[idx] = reminder;
            money[idx] -= gift;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What input are you providing?

Comment: 3  abdul karim hakim  abdul 200 2 karim hakim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing enough input. The loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int idx = map.get(sc.next());
        int gift = sc.nextInt();
        int M = sc.nextInt();
        int reminder =gift%M;
        int dev = gift/M;
        money[idx]=reminder;
        money[idx]-=gift;

    }
```

will run 3 times, as per your input and in every run it will expect one string and two integers. You are providing this input just once.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ,I have found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TestProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Enter a number of friends you want to enter:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int  n = sc.nextInt();   
        int []money=new int[n];
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a name of ther friends you want to enter:");
            String name =sc.next();
            map.put(name, i);
            System.out.println("Enter the number of gifts you want to give:");
            int gift = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the money  you want to spend on the gift:");
            int M = sc.nextInt();
            int reminder =gift%M;
            int dev = gift/M;
            money[i]=reminder;   
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: the program is not getting executed, made changes to ur code , i didn't get what you were trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I have found the problem

Comment: @jisan_bd the problem was you were using same user input for both String and integer